# How to add 100% height to the div in react without height 100vh

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

Here is the code:
I have a div on the left with a light blue colour and it should have a height of 100%

```js
const styles = {width:'80px',backgroundColor:'rgb(241, 242, 250)',height:'100'}

function Leftdash () {
    return (
        <div>
            <div>
                <div style = {styles}>
                <div>hi</div>
                </div>
                
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}



ReactDOM.render(
  <Leftdash />,
  document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

Comment: Do you want to have the background color for the whole page?

Comment: 100% of what ?  A parent or the viewport?

Comment: and why not 100vh

Comment: Not like that, see that 'hi' with the light blue color. That element has a width of 80px and need a height of 100%

Comment: @Ramakay There is a need of flexibility. sometimes the size should change to other values.

Answer (score 2):

you need to set the `height` of `html` and `body` tags (100%), also you need to set the `height` of all parent divs which are there, and after that, if your div's height will be set to `100%` – it will fill with blue color all the height of your `window`

Comment: created a .css fie for the component,how ever it is not working with react

Comment: @Tony css should work fine with React, or any other library. Check the path to the file, or if it loaded correctly at Chrome Dev Tools / Network tab